# Dividir lista en un numero n de datos

Tags: python, python-3.x, lista, bucle-for

Estoy tratando de hacer un reporte automatizado, donde requiero solo 15 datos por reporte.

La problematica es que yo tengo que divir la lista de n datos, en lista de 15 datos. Genere este codigo y funicona pero no es el mejor pues si recibo n datos ya no es funcional alguien podría ser tan amable de orientamere y agradezco el apoyo:

```
def listas(lista):
    hojas = len(lista)
    if hojas <= 15:
        return [lista]
    elif hojas <= 30:
        return[ lista[:15],lista[15:]]
    elif hojas <= 45:
        return [lista[:15],lista[15:30],lista[30:]]
    elif hojas <= 60:
        return [lista[:15],lista[15:30],lista[30:45],lista[:]]
    else:
        return 'ERROR'
```

Obviamente si recibo mas de 45 datos mi programa truena, espero puedan ayudarme

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def listar( lista ):
    hojas = int( len( lista ) / 15 )
    listas = []
    inicio = 0
    fin = 15
    for i in range( hojas ):
        listas.append( lista[inicio:fin] )
        inicio += 15
        fin += 15
    return listas
        
print( listar( lista ))
```

Primero determinas la cantidad de listas que recibes, creas el array que usarás como salida, y dos variables que contengan la posición de inicio y la de final de la primer lista.
Luego el for itera tantas veces como cantidad de listas hay, en cada iteración, agrega a la salida la sub-cadena delimitada por inicio y fin, luego procede a aumentar en "15" el valor de ellas, preparando la próxima iteración.

Comment: Muchas gracias me funciono!!!!

Answer (score 3):

Hay un forma mucho más directa usando *compresiones de listas*:

```py
def listas(lista, size=15):
    return [lista[n:n+size] for n in range(0, len(lista), size)]
```

Cada rebanada será `lista[n:n+size]`, donde `n` es el primer elemento de la rebanada y `size` el tamaño máximo que tendrá la rebanada. Con el `range(0, len(lista), size)` iremos obteniendo los elementos inciales desde dónde hacer el corte.

Answer (score 0):

Lo primero que se me ocurre es que hagas un bucle por cada vez que sea mayor de 15 y que entonces hagas una pasada por cada vez añadiendo una posición al array que devuelves en el return